# bash script to parse file, yield first uncommented line, comment it and use its content

Tags: bash, awk, sed, knockd

I have a file with a long list of sequences, which are comma separated lists of numbers. Lists can be commented out using `#`, e.g.

```
#1,2,3
#4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

I'd like to have a bash command which takes the first uncommented sequence, splits the numbers and passes them to a command (which is knock, used for port knocking), and finally comments out the yielded line.

Running the command a first time on the example above should:

1. run `knock myhost 7 8 9`
2. edit the input file as

   ```
   #1,2,3
   #4,5,6
   #7,8,9
   10,11,12
   ```

I guess there is some super simply way to do this using sed/awk, but I don't know these commands so well.

Thank you in advance

---

**edit** I wish a command that processes only a single line from the input file, not consuming the whole file through a loop

---

**edit2***

I ended up writing this in zsh, thanks for your help

```
#!/bin/zsh
sequences=$HOME/.knock.$1.sequences
read -A line <<< "$(grep "^[^#]" $sequences -m 1 -n)"
IFS=, read -A ports <<< $line[2]
IFS=: read -A linenum <<< $line[1]

knock $1 $ports

if nc -z -w1 $1 22;  
then
         sed -i "$linenum s/^/#/" $sequences
fi
```

Comment: Repeatedly rewriting the file is going to be hideously inefficient. Simply keepnig a count and commenting out that many lines from the start when you are done would be a lot less heavy on I/O (`sed -i "1,${count}s/^/#/" "$file"`). If that's unacceptable, and you absolutely want detailed control, a sequential file is hardly ideal; maybe use a database or a queue system?

Comment: I want a command that each time is executed processes only one line. I won't use that command so often

Comment: @leonixyz, how about you try writing meta-code that expresses how you think the program should work? As it stands, your question may gather downvotes, as it has no code for people to correct. While a few folks here are willing to provide professional programming services at no cost, it really isn't the StackOverflow "way". We want to help you improve your craft, not just provide you with free stuff.

Comment: wrt `I want a command that each time is executed processes only one line` - Should the command choose the line to process at random or do you have some way you'd want to be able to tell the command some specific line you'd like it to process?

Comment: the line should be the first one uncommented

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you essentially want to process the entire file, but keep track of which lines have already been processed in the event of an interruption. I would write a commented version of the input to a second file as you go along, replacing the original input with the temp when the script exits for any reason. Something like

```
trap 'mv tmp "$input"' EXIT
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line = #* ]] && continue   # skip commented lines
    IFS=, read -a arr <<< "$line"
    knock "${arr[@]}"
    echo "#$line" >&3
done < "$input" 3> tmp
```

Comment: Maybe set `IFS=,` seeing as the input is comma-separated.

Comment: I did, in the second `read`. This seemed the simplest way to write out the (commented) original line to the temporary file, rather than rejoining the fields with commas.

Comment: this code consumes the whole file, right? perhaps my question was not well asked: I need a command that only processes *one* line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk based solution to do the same:

```
awk -v tf="$$.tmp" -F, '!done && !/^#/ {
   r="#" $0
   $1 = $1
   cmd = "knock myhost " $0
   while((cmd | getline) > 0)
      print
   close(s)
   done = 1
   $0 = r
}
{
    print > tf
}' file && mv $$.tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
perl -i -aF',' -pe 'if (!$done and s/^(?!#)/#/) { $done=1; @p=@F }
   END { system("knock", @p) if $done }' "$file"
```

The Perl script performs the substitution, and keeps the values from the substituted line in the array `@p`.  When we are done writing the file, we pass the parameters in `@p` to `knock` by way of the `system()` function.

This could be performed in the middle of the loop, of course, in which case however a failure could corrupt the file.  Perhaps you'll want to wrap it with something like

```
perl -i~ -aF',' -pe 'if (!$done and s/^(?!#)/#/) {
   $done=1; system("knock", @F); die "$!" if $? }' "$file" ||
mv "$file~" "$file"
```

which creates a backup `$file~` and moves it back if the `system()` (or something else in the Perl script) fails.